# How to delete permanently/move to trash woocommerce orders that has been canceled automatically?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Is there any plugins or scripts to do this automatically? I am not really good at scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Copy & Paste this code into theme functions.php :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', 
 'prefix_delete_woocommerce_order', 15 );
public function prefix_delete_woocommerce_order( $order_id ){
  wp_delete_post($order_id,true);
}
```

The above code is executed when the order is canceled and causes the order to be deleted. Use the above code carefully because it is not possible to get access to the deleted order later ( it will delete permanently ). If you want to move order to trash, Change second wp_delete_post paramter value to false.